# Can a linux program be run deterministically under emulation?

Tags: linux, runtime, posix, emulation, deterministic

Regardless of language and operation system, its simple to create nondeterminstic programs.
For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::thread t1([](){
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    });
    std::thread t2([](){
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    });
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Due to the above race condition, this program has the potential to print different values each time the program is run.

**Question:**
Without modifying the binary, is there a way to run this program so that it prints the same results every time?  I was thinking there might be some kind of emulator that could run linux programs this way.

Comment: *"Without modifying the binary"* assumes an external process. An obvious solution is to append a `...| sort` pipeline, which should ensure the data always appears in the same order. Probably not what you want. Just an idea. Good luck!

Comment: If this is a purly educational and research-based question: Yes, in theory it is possible. But you would need a statically scheduled system, which is basically impossible for the given case (having an OS or emulator or something)

If you are having a problem with a task you are working on: This is basically the defenition of a XY-Problem. Maybe cou could tell us _what you are actually trying to accomplish_

Comment: @shellter Interesting callout.  External process is right.  I'm looking for some kind of emulator.  I should have come up with a better example because although sorting stdout would work for my example, you could imagine program which prints different output based on the race condition.

Comment: @Malik To be more specific, I'm looking to improve the CI/CD domain where flaky unit tests are a common failure point.  Large companies tend to build statistical models to predict and handle these misbehaving tests.  Perhaps if the nondetermistic OS ran an emulator that forced ordering, things could be made more stable.